# Proxy Protocol with Nginx Reverse Proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, transparent-proxy

### Overview

I have an Nginx reverse proxy setup pointing to a SaaS application (BigCommerce). While my configuration works great, I'm not able to ensure the **client IP** shows in the SaaS backend instead of the **Reverse Proxy IP**. In the SaaS backend, there's no mechanism to add a list of trusted IP addresses or use `set_real_ip_from` and `real_ip_header` so instead I've been tasked to implement `proxy_protocol` on the Reverse Proxy in order to ensure IP headers are passed through the Reverse Proxy with the client's IP instead of its own.

### Configuration

**In `http` `server` context**

```
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;

    # support http 1.1 persistent connections
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
```

### Issue

When I enable `proxy_protocol` on my `listen` directive within the http server context (e.g. `listen 443 ssl http2 proxy_protocol`), I receive a [**`Broken Header`**](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1048) error in nginx and a `connection_reset` in my browser.

Additonally, I've tried enabling `proxy_protocol` via the `stream` context as it's specified in **["Accepting Proxy Protocol"](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/using-proxy-protocol/)** docs by Nginx:

**In `stream` context**

```
stream {
    server {
        listen 12345;
        proxy_pass example.com:12345;
        proxy_protocol on;
    }
}
```

I'm unfamiliar with `proxy_protocol` so I don't know what I'm missing to get this working.

Technically speaking, I'm really trying to make my reverse proxy a 'transparent proxy' but it doesn't seem to work that way with the SaaS Backend because it's logging the proxy IP instead of the client IP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong direction:

1. The `listen 443 ssh http2 proxy_protocol;` directive (cf. [listen](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen)) enables the parsing of the [Proxy Protocol](https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.8/doc/proxy-protocol.txt) on incoming connections. Your browser does not speak the protocol, hence the `Bad Header` error. If you want to see a minimal example of Proxy Protocol use:

   ```
   openssl s_client -connect <nginx_ip>:https -crlf
   ```

   and type:

   ```
   PROXY TCP4 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.1 443 443
   GET / HTTP/1.1
   Host: <nginx_host_name>
   ```

   followed by two blank lines.
2. The `proxy_protocol on;` directive (cf. [proxy_protocol](https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html#proxy_protocol)) would enable the Proxy Protocol between Nginx and the SaaS server. The latter, however, does not support the Proxy Protocol as you say. You'll need to implement it.

However, you have a third solution, which works if **nginx** is on the path between the SaaS server and the Internet:

1. Use the `proxy_bind` directive (cf. [proxy_bind](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_bind)) to tell **nginx** to spoof its source address (to use the one from the client):

   ```
   proxy_bind $remote_addr transparent;
   ```
2. **nginx** can easily spoof the source address, but the response packet from the SaaS server will be routed to the client instead of **nginx**. Therefore you need to intercept the packets coming from the SaaS server. You need a new routing table, let's call it `transparent` by adding:

   ```
   100 transparent
   ```

   to `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`. Then you need to accept any address as local:

   ```
   ip route add local default dev lo table transparent
   ```

   finally you need to add a firewall rule to force the usage of the routing table `transparent` on all traffic coming back from the SaaS server (let's assume its address is `10.10.10.10`):

   ```
   iptable -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 10.10.10.10 --sport 80 -m socket\
   --transparent -j MARK --set-mark 1
   ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup transparent
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your response! If I were to use `proxy_protocol on;` within a `stream` context, do you know how I'd configure that so those headers are passed along with any requests like `client -> reverse_proxy (with proxy_protocol) -> BigCommerce (SaaS Server)`? The problem I may have in solution 3, if I'm understanding correctly, is that if I don't know the IP for the SaaS server I wouldn't be able to catch the traffic specifically from that server?

Comment: If **nginx** is not a router between the clients and the server, you won't intercept the traffic. The `X-Forwarded-For` headers are already sent to the server without activating the Proxy Protocol or anything else. The question is, whether the server interprets them.

Comment: To elaborate, I'm being told to implement `proxy_protocol` on the nginx Reverse Proxy so that IP addresses are forwarded correctly to the BigCommerce (SaaS Server). My `proxy_pass` is passing requests to https://store-xxxxxx.mybigcommerce.com and my `x-forwarded-for` headers are intact with the `client_ip, proxy_ip` but they're stating my `x-real-ip` header needs to be the client's IP which is where I'm having this issue.

Comment: The `X-Real-IP` is already set to the correct value. You are probably testing from behind the same NAT.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. So it's possible my host is not forwarding the correct value and setting `$remote_addr` to the proxy IP? Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: No, your proxy is forwarding the correct value, but **nginx** and the browser on which you are testing appear to have the same IP address (due to Network Address Translation).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105016/discussion-between-cvanorman-and-piotr-p-karwasz).